# VSCode python not finding relitive files in Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm following the [Practical Python Programming](https://dabeaz-course.github.io/practical-python/) course from David Beazley. Having recently switched machines (Ubuntu to Windows 10...i know...) I'm picking this back up.

Environment: Visual Studio Code, using Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) running Ubuntu, all the necessary VSCode extentions applied to work with WSL.

**Context:** python allows you to reference files with code like the below (adapted from the course linked to above). In this case my python module is in a parent directory called `Work`, and within it there is a directory called `Data` that has various files in it.

```
read_data('Data/portfolio.csv', 'Data/prices.csv')
```

With WSL, you can launch VSCode by doing `code .` and hitting enter in a Windows Terminal once you are in the directory with a file you want to edit. In my case, doing so in my `Work` directory (on Ubuntu WSL) starts VSCode and I can run a python file, and as I would expect, I can find the files in the `Data/` directory (to be clear, the `read_data(...` function works).

**Issue:** if I come into WSL via the Windows GIU first (i.e. clicking the shortcut on my Windows 10 desktop), navigate to the folder on WSL with my code, and run the same file...I get python errors to say it can't find the files I'm referencing. My fix is to reference the full file path.

Why would this be? I've noticed if I do a `print Path.cwd()` using pathlib while running the file as described above in "Issue" then the working directory is my Ubuntu `home`, not the directory where the code is.

Is there an interpreter setting or config in VSCode I'm missing?

Comment: Usually the root path is '\\wsl$\Ubuntu\'

Comment: @PabloDíaz and so why would this be my issue here? I've not had this issue in other IDE's? Is there something I need to change in vscode? Or is this a querk of using WSL